# Formatting JSON for empty or Null values

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, ssis

I have issue with Data in DB (SQL Server). My DB columns has mixture of both Relational data and JSON type data. Few json columns got incorrectly populated. Need C# code to fix the issue.

Example consider my Table name is 
dbo.Organization.

And columns are

orgReferenceNumber, organizationAssociation.

And organizationAssociation is a JSON type column. Below is the data being populated.

> `[{"associatedToId":null,"associationType":null,"isObsolete":null}`

since all attributes are in null in above json expected output is []

Need C# code which iterates through all records of particular column and checks if all attributes of JSON are empty or NULL. If empty/NULL then just overwrite it to [].

Update: Adding code SSIS C# code Script Component. Below the point where i am facing the issue. `object val = objProp.GetValue(value, null);`

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException   HResult=0x8002000E
>   Message=Parameter count mismatch.

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
#endregion

namespace ST_cecd1942b9e44e899c1e9e560039f2c3
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool StringPropertiesEmpty(this object value)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo objProp in value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (objProp.CanRead)
                {
                    object val = objProp.GetValue(value, null);
                    if (val.GetType() == typeof(string))
                    {
                        if (val == "" || val == null)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {



        public void Main()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection;
            ConnectionManager strcon = Dts.Connections["UCP_Q"];
            connection = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)strcon.AcquireConnection(null);
            string sql = "select organisationReferenceNumber,organizationAssociation from dbo.organisation";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            long CRN;
            String Json;

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    CRN = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetValue(0));
                    Json = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1));
                    //   JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(Json);

                    bool checkNull =  ExtensionMethods.StringPropertiesEmpty(Json.Replace("\"", ""));

                    //if(checkNull=='true')
                    //{

                    //}


                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }



    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far, and where you are stuck -- i.e. a [mcve]?  Is the problem in serializing JSON without null attributes, accessing values in a database, or what?

Comment: updated the post with the code which i have sofar. And also error message.